# How works the "withANYTHING" way of passing variables to the session in Laravel?

Tags: php, laravel

In Laravel, I know that

```
return Redirect::back()->with(['Foo'=>'Bar']);
```

is equivalent to

```
return Redirect::back()->withFoo('Bar');
```

But... how does it work? I mean, creating a new function `withFoo` on the fly to pass a variable? Where is this behaviour defined inside the Laravel code? Where can I check it?

Comment: It's the `__set()` magic method(although I didn't check, I'm pretty sure that's the case). Laravel is full of "magic". I was wrong, see KA_lin's answer.

Comment: Actually it's `__call()` , check an example here http://www.garfieldtech.com/blog/magical-php-call

Comment: You can check the `RedirectResponse.php` there you can find all methods of `with*` `Line No: 191 _call()`

Comment: Wow, that's exactly what I wanted! Why don't you make an answer with it so I can accept it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's how it's implemented ([source](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/a1dc78820d2dbf207dbdf0f7075f17f7021c4ee8/src/Illuminate/Http/RedirectResponse.php#L192)):

```
public function __call($method, $parameters)
{
    if (Str::startsWith($method, 'with')) {
        return $this->with(Str::snake(substr($method, 4)), $parameters[0]);
    }
    throw new BadMethodCallException("Method [$method] does not exist on Redirect.");
}
```

Remember, magic method [__call](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.overloading.php#object.call) is triggered when one attempts to invoke a method otherwise inaccessible. The first parameter is the method's name, followed by parameters passed. In this particular case, [RedirectResponse->with()](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/a1dc78820d2dbf207dbdf0f7075f17f7021c4ee8/src/Illuminate/Http/RedirectResponse.php#L39) is triggered, setting up flash data:

```
public function with($key, $value = null)
{
    $key = is_array($key) ? $key : [$key => $value];
    foreach ($key as $k => $v) {
        $this->session->flash($k, $v);
    }
    return $this;
}
```

Comment: I personally think this way of programming makes debugging and code browsing quite hellish...

Comment: Well, there are two sides to every coin, especially that DRY.